# Ideal sheaf of $Z$ twisted by $Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, characteristic-classes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular projective surface and $Z$ a 1-dimensional subscheme (i.e. a curve) and $m:= c_2(I_Z)$.

1. What (geometrically) is $m$? What is the intuition behind it?
2. What is $I_Z(Z)$? In particular, is this $0$-dimensional?

Comment: Where did you see these referred to? Since $I_Z \cong \mathcal O_X(-Z)$, the ideal sheaf is a line bundle hence only has nonzero $c_0$ and $c_1$. And we also have $I_Z(Z) \cong I_Z \otimes \mathcal O_X(Z) \cong \mathcal O_X(-Z+Z) \cong \mathcal O_X$.

Comment: It is mentioned in the beginning of section 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08899.pdf.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. A $1$-dimensional subscheme here is not necessarily of *pure* dimension $1$, i.e. it is a union of curves and points. So everything in my previous comment does not hold. I'm not too familiar with the behavior of Chern classes for such ideal sheaves, and I am (at least right now) to tired to try and work it out.